# registerForActivityResult in fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to call `registerForActivityResult()` inside a fragment, when it finishes running it simply closes the fragment, which is a problem. How can I call `registerForActivityResult()` from a fragment without closing it?

```
private val profileImageLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result != null && result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        profileImageUri = result.data?.data

        try {
            profileImageUri?.let { profileImageUri ->
               if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
                    val bitmap: Bitmap = getBitmap(activity?.contentResolver, profileImageUri)

                    context?.let { context ->
                        Glide.with(context).load(bitmap).into(pfpIV)
                        // here it closes the fragment
                    }
                } else {
                    context?.let { context ->
                        val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(context.contentResolver, profileImageUri)
                        var bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
                        bitmap =  bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
                        Glide.with(context).load(bitmap).into(pfpIV)
                        // here it closes the fragment
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e:IOException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code looks good to me, what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: You can use the `launch()` function on `profileImageLauncher` variable, it should work fine even in a fragment

Comment: I used the `launch()` function, the issue is that for some reason, this seems to close the fragment & I have no error or anything

Comment: What do you exactly want to when you launch the activity?

Comment: you try to open a fragment to just launch resultLauncher, then close the fragment ?... if the fragment rule just launch this intent, why you just launch it from activity/ fragment instead of creating a fragment for it ?

Comment: Are you trying to get image from gallery ?

Comment: your code is fine use   ` launch()`   function on   ` profileImageLauncher `   I try it work fine with me

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get an image from the gallery, I believe my code is fine yet the fragment closes after choosing an image

Comment: Allow me to clerify, when I choose an image and the registerForActivityResult code runs, the app reopens the main activity on the firsts fragment and not the fragment in which I chose the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the only solution I found was to use an activity, it seems that when using `registerForActivityResult` it returns me to the activity, not the fragment, so if you were in a fragment that wasn't the activitie's main/default you won't be able to return to it, the function will return you to the main fragment for the activity since it's technichally opening a new intent to get the information from the user (image in this case), so it has to return to the activity and cannot return to the fragment.